# Backup to the null device on SQL Server for Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux

In SQL Server on Windows, it's a common enough thing to backup a database to the [NULL device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev/null) if you need to take a backup but don't actually care about that backup.  This is useful for changing the recovery model in a dev environment, as an example.

The backup statement is something like:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [xyz] TO DISK = 'NUL:';
```

In SQL Server for Linux, one might assume `/dev/null` would be the logical equivalent, however if you attempt that:

> Processed 125224 pages for database 'xyz', file 'xyz01' on file 1.
>   Processed 2 pages for database 'xyz', file 'xyzLog' on file 1.
>   Msg 3634, Level 16, State 2, Line 16
>   The operating system returned the error '31(A device attached to the system is   not functioning.)' while attempting 'DiskChangeFileSize' on '/dev/null'.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

The above command *does appear* to reset the `log_reuse_wait` and `log_reuse_wait_desc` columns in `sys.databases`, so perhaps `/dev/null` really does work.

I'm using SQL Server on Linux v14.0.900.75 on RedHat Enterprise Linux 7.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "typical" SQL Server syntax does actually work in SQL Server for Linux; so try:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [xyz] TO DISK = 'NUL';
```